# Installing Ubuntu From An USB With Limited Conditions

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb, windows, flash

here is my situation:

I have 2 computers, one with Windows 8 and another (a laptop) in which I want to install Ubuntu from an USB Flash (currently I don't have any operative system installed in the laptop).

My intentions are to use the former computer to prepare the USB installer,

***I CAN NOT DOWNLOAD ANY AUXILIARY SOFTWARE**.*

I also have the ISO file: "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso" and my Flash capacity is 8 GB.

I already tried making the flash booteable from the windows command prompt and then coping the files inside the ISO but this seems not work.

Can anybody help me to install ubuntu in my laptop in this particular situation ?
Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: download `unetbootin` for windows,and make bootable usb.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I can not download any auxiliary software, I asking for a way to do that directly from windows

Comment: You are asking `how to make a bootable ubuntu disk from windows command prompt`,am i correct?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, not necessarily from command prompt, just without download any auxiliary software.

Answer (score 0):

[pen drive linux universal installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) very useful and very ease to use. It need not be installed ) just download and execute it

Comment: Thanks but, I can not download any auxiliary software

Comment: Are you kidding? 1.1 MB is not so more. You consume more quantity of internet traffic verifying if it's new replies on askubuntu until you find a solution without auxiliary software

Comment: One page on askubuntu has ~450 KB, ignoring cache of course.

Comment: I am not kidding. It's not about quantity of internet traffic, it's possible that I am in Cuba for example. I just make a perfectly legal question, please read it. Can you download it and send it me by email :-) :-)

Comment: ok. I understand, in this situation you can install ubuntu in your on your current computer using wubi.exe, and use `Startup disk creator` to make the bootable USB stick, after this you can remove ubuntu like a windows program. Windows 8 can mount a iso image without any auxiliary program.

Comment: Except Windows 8 and WUBI don't mix.

Comment: @ubfan1 I try wubi only on windows xp, i didn't knew than it work

Comment: ok guys thanks a lot for your time, but wubi don't work for me because I want to install ubuntu in the other computer , the laptop one, which have not any OS installed ...

Comment: You're looking for the Windows equivalent to "dd", a program which reads/writes raw blocks.  Use that to write the iso to the usb device.  Maybe your cdrom writer program can "burn" an image to the usb?  Try a Windows support group for knowledge of Windows tools.